# Sharing Code between Razor Pages in Blazor Project

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a method in my Razor page, that needs to be used in all my razor pages.

```
async Task ShowNotification(NotificationMessage message)
{
    notificationService.Notify(message);

    await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
}
```

What is the best practice to be able to share this method between razor pages and not have to put this method in each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your pages inherit a base class, and put this method into that base class.

NotifyingPage.cs

```
public abstract class NotifyingPage : ComponentBase
{
    async Task ShowNotification(NotificationMessage message)
    {
        notificationService.Notify(message);

        await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
    }
}
```

SomeRazorPage.razor

```
@page "/something"
@inherits NotifyingPage

<div>Whatever</div>
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ShowNotification("Initialized!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The base class should derived from `ComponentBase`